# How can we stop an: "root.after(time.function)" loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

Can you please help me i have the following code:

```
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("100x200")
    root.resizable(0, 0)

    def loop():
        print("test")
        root.after(1000,loop)

    button=Button(root, text="Start Loop", command=loop).place(x=10,y=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

and i want, at some point, to stop the after loop, manually or automatically called by another def.
How can we stop the Loop?

Comment: That's essentially recursion, and to stop a recursive function, you add in a *base-case* that specifies a stop condition.

Comment: If you save the result of `.after()`, you can call `.after_cancel()` on it later.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for your advises.

seams to work with this approach :

```
var=None   #I have given this variable an value 

def start_loop():
    global var
    print("test")
    button_start.configure(text="Stop Loop", command=stop_loop)
    var = root.after(1000,start_loop)   # now the variable has this value

def stop_loop():
    button_start.configure(text="Start Loop", command=start_loop)
    root.after_cancel(var)  # apply the command for this var which is the loop started early  

button_start=Button(root, text="Start Loop", command=start_loop)
button_start.place(x=10,y=10)
```

Hope this is a correct way, i was looking for this for a loooong time!